# How to $pull embedded documents that are not in a given list from a Mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, pull

I have a Mongo collection called documents which has the following structure:

```
{
  name: "..."
  tokens: [
    {
       _id: <string (unique)>,
       tf: <integer>,
       tf_idf: <float>
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have a list of tokens that I want to keep. Is it somehow possible to build up a query using `$pull` to delete all tokens whose id is not contained in the list?

The following does not work:

```
db.documents.update({name: "foo"}, { 
   $pull : { 
       $not : {
           $elemMatch : { 'tokens' : { '_id' : ['foo', 'bar'] }}
       }
   }
})
```

The only alternative I see so far is iterating over all documents and checking on the client whether or not to keep the token and eventually delete them one by one. I'd rather use an approach which does not involve pulling all data to the client just to check which tokens can be deleted and which not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let's consider these datas :

```
> db.nicolas.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4edfd6551757be3330db7c75"), 
          "tokens" : [ { "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 }, { "id" : 3 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4edfd50452d5d16ccc1aa7b5"), 
          "tokens" : [ { "id" : 3 }, { "id" : 4 }, { "id" : 5 } ] }
```

If I apply these transformation :

```
> db.nicolas.update({_id: ObjectId("4edfd6551757be3330db7c75")}, 
                    {$pull:{tokens: { id :{$nin:[1,2]}} } })
```

I'll get the following :

```
> db.nicolas.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4edfd6551757be3330db7c75"), 
          "tokens" : [ { "id" : 1 }, { "id" : 2 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4edfd50452d5d16ccc1aa7b5"), 
          "tokens" : [ { "id" : 3 }, { "id" : 4 }, { "id" : 5 } ] }
```

So, for your case, something like this should work :

```
> db.documents.update({name: "foo"}, 
                      {$pull: {tokens: { _id : {$nin:['foo','bar']}} } })
```

Does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to keep only the tokens whose _id value matches "foo" or "bar", correct?

Given the collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ 
"_id" : 1, 
"name" : "Doc1", 
"tokens" : [    
    { 
    "_id" : "foo",
    "tf" : 1,
    "tf_idf" : 1 
    },  
    {
    "_id" : "buzz",
    "tf" : 2,
    "tf_idf" : 2 
    } 
]
},
{ 
"_id" : 2, 
"name" : "Doc2", 
"tokens" : [    
    {
    "_id" : "bar",
    "tf" : 3,
    "tf_idf" : 3 
    },
    {
    "_id" : "bing",
    "tf" : 4,
    "tf_idf" : 4 
    }
]
}
```

The following update should accomplish what you are looking to do.  This will remove all subdocuments whose _id value matches "foo" or "bar" from the "tokens" array of each document.

```
> db.test.update({}, {$pull:{tokens:{_id:{$nin:["foo", "bar"]}}}}, false, true)
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Doc1", "tokens" : [ { "_id" : "foo", "tf" : 1, "tf_idf" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Doc2", "tokens" : [ { "_id" : "bar", "tf" : 3, "tf_idf" : 3 } ] }
```

The Mongo Documentation on the $pull operator may be found here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

Hopefully this is will help you to do what you need to.  Good luck!